# Email Reminder not sending

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, smtp, reminders

I am  new to MVC and trying to create a manual email reminder. It is a button which will be pressed at the start of each day to send reminder emails to patient that they're last appointment was 2 years ago. However nothing appears to be sending. For testing purposes I have changed the reminder to todays day as opposed to 2 years ago.

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Email2Year()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Email2Year(Appointment model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var query = (from d in db.Appointments
                where d.Date == DateTime.Now.Date
                select d);

            foreach (var d in query)
            {

            var body = "<p>Hi {0}</p><p>Appointment reminder, You last appointment was {1}. We recomend you make an appointment every 2 year....";
            var message = new MailMessage();
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(d.Patient.User.Email)); 
            message.From = new MailAddress("XXXXX@gmail.com");  
            message.Subject = "Your email subject";
            message.Body = string.Format(body, d.Patient.User.FirstName, d.Date);
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;

            using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
                var credential = new NetworkCredential
                {
                    UserName = "XXXXX@gmail.com",  // replace with valid value
                    Password = "XXXXXXX"  // replace with valid value
                };
                smtp.Credentials = credential;
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
            }
                return RedirectToAction("Sent");
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult Sent()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: When you say "nothing appears to be sending" how are you making this determination? Are you getting an error? Is it perhaps sending just fine but the recipients are not receiving them?

Comment: are any exceptions being thrown? Could the mails actually be sending, but going straight to spam folders? Has the "allow less secure applications" setting been configured on  the Gmail account? Has 2-factor authentication been set on the gmail account?

Comment: @user1666620 No no exceptions are being thrown. I have that it should send to another email address of mine, however it is not recieved. I have also checked the junk mail

Comment: Has the "allow less secure applications" setting been configured on the Gmail account? Has 2-factor authentication been set on the gmail account?

Comment: @BenRobinson I am sending it to another email address of mine and it is not being recieved. No errors are being thrown

Comment: What happens when you set breakpoints and step through the code on your dev machine?

Comment: @user1666620 yes. I have sent emails manually by Adding the email address, the problem occurs when I try to loop through the query

Comment: What do you mean "problem" and "try to"? does something unexpected happen? Does the loop fail?

Comment: @user1666620 I am redirected to the "Sent" page but I do not receive an email

Comment: can you answer my questions about how you configured the gmail account?

Comment: @user1666620 I configured it in the gmail settings to allow less secure apps, and was able to send emails from the application when i entered a email address into  message.To.Add(new MailAddress("XXXX@XXXX.com"));

Comment: so does it work now? When you step through the code, what is the value of `d.Patient.User.Email`? Also, do the email appear in the sent draft or outbox folders?

Comment: @user1666620 It works if I comment out the query and enter an email address in To.Add(new address). The value of d.Patient.User.Email is the email address I am trying to send the email to

Comment: but are you absolutely certain that when the code runs the value is populated correctly? also, have you checked the other gmail folders as i suggested?

Comment: @user1666620 Yes I have checked the sent and drafts, nothing is there and the value populates correctly

Comment: Can't be entirely sure, but I'm fairly sure that your problem is in your 'query'.  '.Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities, although I'm not sure that's what you are using either.  But, the fact that you said that when you manually enter in an email address the mail is sent without a problem, that would lead me to believe that your query doesn't have any results, hence no emails being generated.